# Escaping character only when it appears between parenthesis

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I've searched around the internet and tried many combinations but I can not seem to get this to work.

I am trying to write a script that creates LaTeX table code. It all works fine until I have an ampersand inside one of the values, e.g.,

```
{1702} & {12389122} & {Topic 1 Online Quiz} & {1.7} & {2} & {83.3} \\\hline 
{1702} & {12389122} & {Topic 2 & 3 Online Q...} & {1.9} & {2} & {93.3} \\\hline
{1702} & {12389122} & {Topic 4 Online Quiz} & {} & {2} & {} \\\hline
{1702} & {12389122} & {Topic 5 Online Quiz ...} & {} & {2} & {} \\\hline
```

I need to be able to read in the input.txt file containing this data and then output the result to output.txt file, with the same data apart from in line 2 I need to escape the ampersand, e.g.,

```
{1702} & {12389122} & {Topic 1 Online Quiz} & {1.7} & {2} & {83.3} \\\hline 
{1702} & {12389122} & {Topic 2 \& 3 Online Q...} & {1.9} & {2} & {93.3} \\\hline
{1702} & {12389122} & {Topic 4 Online Quiz} & {} & {2} & {} \\\hline
{1702} & {12389122} & {Topic 5 Online Quiz ...} & {} & {2} & {} \\\hline
```

But ONLY to escape the ampersand(s) that appear between the {}

I think I may have been closer earlier, but my last attempt was the following:

```
sed 's/\({[a-zA-Z0-9. _]*\)\(\&\)\([a-zA-Z0-9. _]*}.*\)/\1\\\2\3/' input.txt > output.txt
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The below code works for me

```
sed 's/{\([^}]*\)&\([^}]*\)}/{\1\\\&\2}/g' input.txt > output.txt
```

Explanation:
The `/g` flag of `sed` command performs substitution across the entire line. In absence of `/g` flag, `sed` performs only first substitution per line.

In the 'search' field of `sed` command, I am starting with `{`, looking for all characters that are NOT `}` and stop at `&`. Then I am looking for all characters again that are not `}` until I encounter first `}'. This restricted search ensures that I find`&`that is strictly within closest`{`and`}`. Then I am replacing the same with escaped`&`.

Note: This will only replace ONE `&` within a given pair of curly braces. If you have more than ONE `&`, you will need to modify the regular expression.

Comment: You don't need the tail part of the regexp: `sed 's/\({[^&}]*\)&/\1\\\&/g' file`

Comment: That's true @EdMorton. I added the tail part in the regexp so that it becomes expandable to the OP in case there is a need to support more than one `&` in the input data. Something line `sed 's/{\([^}]*\)&\([^}]*\)&\([^}]*\)}/{\1\\\&\2\\&\3}/g' input.txt > output.txt`... and so on.

Comment: If that can happen then the OP should just use GNU awk where you can call gensub() in a while loop (and I'm sure there's some GNU sed wizardry involving 30 single characters plus the batman symbol to do the same but then why would you....).

Answer (score 0):

If `perl` is okay

```
$ echo '{1702} & {Topic 2 & 3 Online Q}' | perl -pe 's/\{[^}]+\}/$&=~s|&|\\&|gr/ge'
{1702} & {Topic 2 \& 3 Online Q}
$ echo '{1 & 7 & 0 & 2} & {Topic 2 & 3}' | perl -pe 's/\{[^}]+\}/$&=~s|&|\\&|gr/ge'
{1 \& 7 \& 0 \& 2} & {Topic 2 \& 3}
```

- `\{[^}]+\}` match `{` followed by non `}` characters and ending with `}`

  - nesting is not handled, for ex: `{17 {3 & 3} & 02}` will give `{17 {3 \& 3} & 02}`
- `/ge` to replace all occurrences and allow Perl code to be used in replacement section
- `$&=~s|&|\\&|gr` replace all `&` with `\&` only on matched text

With `sed`, tested on `GNU sed`, syntax might vary for other implementations

```
$ echo '{1 & 7 & 0 & 2} & {Topic 2 & 3}' | sed -E ':a s/(\{[^}]*[^\\])&([^}]*\})/\1\\\&\2/; ta'
{1 \& 7 \& 0 \& 2} & {Topic 2 \& 3}
```

- `:a` label
- `\{[^}]*[^\\]` match `{` followed by zero or more `}` characters and a non `\` character
- `&` match `&` but not if preceded by `\` courtesy `[^\\]`
- `[^}]*\}` remaining characters, can be skipped I think
- `\1\\\&\2` will prefix `\` to `&`
- `ta` loop to label `a` until substitution succeeds